# How can I use it in singleton mode await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, dio

I want to add cookie management to the network request library dio when I initialize the class, but getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() is an asynchronous method. I tried many methods, but I couldn’t find a way to instantiate this class.

```
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio_cookie_manager/dio_cookie_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat/config/global_config.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class HttpUtil {
  static final HttpUtil _instance =  HttpUtil._internal();
  static Dio? dio;
  static Directory? appDocDir;

  factory HttpUtil() => _instance;

  HttpUtil._internal(){
    dio = Dio();
    String? appDocPath = appDocDir?.path;
    var cj = PersistCookieJar(ignoreExpires: true, storage: FileStorage(appDocPath! +"/.cookies/" ));
    dio?.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cj));
  }
  
   static void getAppDocDir() async {
     appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `await` on `getAppDocDir` function something like this

```
      class HttpUtil {
      static final HttpUtil _instance = HttpUtil._internal();
      static Dio? dio;
      static Directory? appDocDir;

      factory HttpUtil() => _instance;

      HttpUtil._internal() {
        dio = Dio();
        String? appDocPath = appDocDir?.path;
        var cj = PersistCookieJar(
            ignoreExpires: true, storage: FileStorage(appDocPath! + "/.cookies/"));
        dio?.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cj));
      }

      static Future getAppDocDir() async {
        appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      }
    }

    Future<void> checkForFile() async {
      final documentsDirecoty =await HttpUtil.getAppDocDir();
    }
```